# Simple question about delta-Dirac function

Tags: dirac-delta

I can not understand this mathematical formula:

$$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$$

I understand that it is the derivative of an integral evaluated in $a$, but still can not explain in mathematically.

How do you get $f(a)$ from the integral side? and what are the assumptions you have to do?

Comment: That is usually how the $\delta$ is defined, it is "something that if you do this integral together multiplied with any (sufficiently well behaving) $f$ the result becomes $f(a)$".

Comment: Yes @IsaacBrowne is right the definition has integral limits $-\infty,\infty$. But which function could give $f(a)$ if $\delta$ does any considerable things to $f$ far away from $a$.

Comment: There should be a mathematical demonstration of that equality

Comment: I think it is dependent which space of test functions $f$ belongs to. A popular choice is the Schwartz class of infinitely smoothly differentiable functions $f\in \mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Thanks. So in that case *f(a)* is out of the integral an the rest is simple.., but still i am not sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find a great answer [here](http://www.nada.kth.se/~annak/diracdelta.pdf)** (pags 2-3)